# MySQL: A weird query: select a field with many records

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
----------
id |  name |  tel  |  email
----------
1    john    0241    re@yah
2            0534    re@rra
3            435     fd@rar
4    geo     43435   re@eae
5            2347    ui@ear
6            678     re@yaya
```

I want to make a query like this:

```
SELECT tel, email FROM table  WHERE name='geo'
```

and the output to be like that:

```
----------
  tel  |  email

----------

43435   re@eae
2347    ui@ear
678     re@yaya
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why should it include those records when they don't have `name='geo'?

Comment: Hello, the community is strict here. You have to ask a proper question. Btw. You have only one record with name 'geo', so this query will output you '43435   re@eae'

Comment: what is this with missing names in table? is this your real table data? if so, query will return only 4th row.

Comment: please describe what you want (you obviously have some wish for the output, but how did you come by those 3?), what you tried (you obviously did think because of the query, but that doesn't give you the result), and why you tried that.

Comment: The records are independent of each other, so your records in lines 5 and 6 have nothing which indicates that they belong to `geo`. So no, this is not possible with SQL :-)

Comment: not sure what u wanna do ?

Comment: @DadaDom Of course it's possible. Not easy, though.

Comment: It is possible - under certain assumptions - and because there is the `id` column.

Comment: You must store the name with every row. Or better still if one person can have multiple phone numbers and multiple emails you need 3 tables. One for Person, one for PhoneNumbers and one for EmailAddresses, as I would bet people have more email addresses than phone numbers. Then you link them together using the ID of the Person.

Comment: I think you should really fix your table. Run an `UPDATE` to set the empty name to something meaningful

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply. But, it's possible to INSERT in field `name` the missing value('john' and 'geo') , with PHP ?!

Comment: if missing value should always be filled with previous name field that is not empty then it is not complicated.

Comment: @tombom Only, if you assume or make sure that the id is increasing and the next entries without a name belong to that same one - but I didn't see this assumption, so in general I'd say it's not possible. :-)

Comment: @DaDaDom True, added that very same sentence of yours to my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tel, email
FROM table1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(startid) startid,
            IFNULL(MAX(endid), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1)) endid
     FROM (SELECT id startid, NULL endid FROM table1 WHERE name = 'geo'
           UNION
           SELECT NULL, MIN(id)-1 FROM table1
           WHERE name != ''
           AND id > (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'geo')) x) y
ON id BETWEEN startid AND endid
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e6758/4)

Comment: Quite like this solution as it avoids the user variables my solution relies on (which are not that readable, and too many people who might need to maintain the select do not understand them). Had a play and using the same logic but using mainly joins I have simplified it a touch I think

Comment: @Kickstart Yeah, I wasn't crazy about all the nesting and repeats of `geo`. I figured there would be a better way with LEFT JOIN, but too tired to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tel, name FROM
(SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'geo') a
LEFT JOIN table b ON
b.id = a.id
WHERE b.id >= a.id AND b.id < (SELECT id from table WHERE name > '' 
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT 1) c
```

Comment: This will get you all records that are stored after you match the record 'geo'

Comment: I don't think it's that simple, he probably wants them only up to the next row that has a real name filled in.

Comment: `WOOPS`. That will return every row where id is greater than the row containing 'geo' i.e. the rest of his table.

Comment: That's the whole data set we've been provided with

Comment: You need to extrapolate, it's obviously.

Comment: Probably not to someone who came up with that table design in the first place.

Comment: answer should be usefull even if new values are added,not only for his few presented rows. I doubt in production he ll have few rows.

Answer (score 1):

Using user variables:-

```
SELECT tel, email
FROM
(
    SELECT Sub1.id, Sub1.name, Sub1.tel, Sub1.email, @name:=IF(name IS NULL, @name, name) AS aName
    FROM (SELECT * FROM geoname ORDER BY id) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @name:="") Sub2
) Sub3
WHERE aName = 'geo'
```

As Barmar highlighted, this only works if the name field has NULL in it when empty rather than ''. If it needs to cope with blanks as well as NULL:-

```
SELECT tel, email
FROM
(
    SELECT Sub1.id, Sub1.name, Sub1.tel, Sub1.email, @name:=IF(name IS NULL OR name = "", @name, name) AS aName
    FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY id) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @name:="") Sub2
) Sub3
WHERE aName = 'geo'
```

Had a bit more of a play. Quite liked the solution by Barmar but had a play to see if I could simplify and remove a couple of subselects:-

```
SELECT a.*
FROM geoname a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id AS MinId, IFNULL(MIN(b.id), MAX(c.id)) AS MaxId
    FROM geoname a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN geoname b
    ON a.id < b.id AND b.name IS NOT NULL
    CROSS JOIN geoname c
    WHERE a.name = 'geo'
    GROUP BY a.id
) Sub1
ON a.id BETWEEN Sub1.MinId AND Sub1.MaxId
```

Seems marginally quicker and has a simpler explain.

Or to cope with blanks as well as NULLS

```
SELECT a.*
FROM geoname a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id AS MinId, IFNULL(MIN(b.id), MAX(c.id)) AS MaxId
    FROM geoname a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN geoname b
    ON a.id < b.id AND b.name IS NOT NULL OR b.name = ''
    CROSS JOIN geoname c
    WHERE a.name = 'geo'
    GROUP BY a.id
) Sub1
ON a.id BETWEEN Sub1.MinId AND Sub1.MaxId
```

Comment: In the SQL fiddle the name field is blank while this is assuming a NULL field. Easy mod to get it to deal with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the id is increasing and the next entries without a name belong to that same one, it would be the easiest to update your table accordingly.

Here's how:

```
Test data:
/*
drop table yourTable;
CREATE TABLE yourTable
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(40), `tel` int, `email` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO yourTable
    (`id`, `name`, `tel`, `email`)
VALUES
    (1, 'john', 0241, 're@yah'),
    (2, NULL, 0534, 're@rra'),
    (3, NULL, 435, 'fd@rar'),
    (4, 'geo', 43435, 're@eae'),
    (5, NULL, 2347, 'ui@ear'),
    (6, NULL, 678, 're@yaya'),
     (7, 'anything', 789, 'whatever')
;
#*/


UPDATE yourTable yt1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT
yt.*,
COALESCE(name, @prev) AS newName,
CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN @prev:=name END
FROM
yourTable yt
, (SELECT @prev:=NULL) v
ORDER BY id
) yt2 ON yt1.id = yt2.id
SET yt1.name = yt2.newName;

SELECT * FROM yourTable;
```

Result:

```
id    name       tel    email
1    john        241    re@yah
2    john        534    re@rra
3    john        435    fd@rar
4    geo         43435  re@eae
5    geo         2347   ui@ear
6    geo         678    re@yaya
7    anything    789    whatever
```

Then your query should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.id, i.tel, i.email
FROM 
    tableX AS t
  JOIN
    tableX AS i
      ON  i.id >= t.id
      AND i.id < COALESCE(
          ( SELECT n.id
            FROM tableX AS n
            WHERE n.id > t.id
              AND n.name <> ''
            ORDER BY n.id ASC 
              LIMIT 1
          ), 2147483647)
WHERE
    t.name = 'geo' ;
```

Tested at [SQL-Fiddle-1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a15b6/1) (thnx @Barmar)